# Pyspark : how to get specific file based on date to load into dataframe from list of file

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I'm trying to load a specific file from group of file.

example : I have files in hdfs in this format app_name_date.csv, i have 100's of files like this in a directory. i want to load a csv file into dataframe based on date.

dataframe1 = spark.read.csv("hdfs://XXXXX/app/app_name_+$currentdate+.csv")
but its throwing error since $currentdate is not accepting and says file doesnot exists

error :
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: hdfs://XXXXX/app/app_name_+$currentdate+.csv"

any idea how to do this in pyspark

Answer (score 0):

You can format the string with:

```
from datetime import date
formatted = date.today().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
f"hdfs://XXXXX/app/app_name_{formatted}.csv"
```

Out[25]: 'hdfs://XXXXX/app/app_name_02/03/2022.csv'

Answer (score 0):

use this option from datetime package
[image]